# cedet-semantic error "Idle Service Error semantic-idle-summary-idle-function - Arithmetic error" when parsing linux kernel file "jiffies.h"

Tags: c++, c, linux, emacs, cedet

I browsed linux kernel code with emacs-24.5.1, and cedet(inlined in emacs ) for semactic parsing.

After some usual configurations, I opened init/main.c with emacs and some hints like "Parsing *file *% ... Done" appeared, this proves that the cedet-semantic was working. However, an error occurred when parsing "jiffies.h", the error was
"Idle Service Error semantic-idle-summary-idle-function - Arithmetic error".

I googled this error to find a solution and just found a maillist:
http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17681

Obviously, this error was caused by a bug of semantic, semantic can not parse arithmetic macro correctly. Unfortunately, I did not find a solution to this problem.

how can I avoid this error? update cedet? Maybe the cedet in emacs-24.5.1 is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. just install the latest  cedet from http://sourceforge.net/p/cedet/git/ci/master/tree/

Why the version of cedet in emacs is 2.0? This make me feel that it is the latest version. It now seems not. At least, a bug exists.