# CEDET compatibility with Emacs 24.5

Tags: emacs, cedet

After I have updated my Emacs from 24.3 to 24.5 version, my 1.1 version of cedet (highlight, auto completion and summary function) has stopped working for c mode. When I trying to load these semantic mode individually, I got the following messages:

*Buffer myfile.cpp was not set up for parsing*

I think someone has asked a similar question in the past:

[cedet-semantic error "Idle Service Error semantic-idle-summary-idle-function - Arithmetic error" when parsing linux kernel file "jiffies.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554055/cedet-semantic-error-idle-service-error-semantic-idle-summary-idle-function-a/31577541#31577541)

However, I am not sure which snapshot version he has downloaded & how to install a snapshot CEDET version. Can someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggled for a while, I figured out something trivial but hard to see. Hopefully this answer will help others who has experienced the same problem.

When I started to use emacs version 24.3 I didn't know the Cedet version 2.0 was already a built-in package at that time. I downloaded Cedet 1.1 version from 
[Cedet SourceForge](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) website.

And configured that according to some tutorial online by loading my downloaded 1.1 cedet.el file.

Surprisingly this Cedet 1.1 package is still compatible with emacs 24.3 version. Unfortunately this is not the case for emacs 24.5 version, the semantic mode encountered some problem with c mode. Therefore the best solution is to switch back to the built-in Cedet 2.0 version.

If you have used the older version of Cedet, it's possible that the old saved .semanticdb files are not compatible with latest Cedet semanticdb. You can do

> rm -rf ~/.semanticdb/

So the new version semanticdb can create and use the new version of semanticdb (my friend helped me with that subtle problem so I can get the built-in Cedet 2.0 up and running).